# Prevent Axios from sending specific headers

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I am working with Vuejs and i have one problem
I want to send custom Headers to my backend API but not to a third Party API.

i have tried to create an axios instance to solve my case to no avail. The Custom Headers are sent to the third Party API which is of course blocked by CORS and thus i dont get the Results i expect. I figure that i did set the custom header globally in the Vue `main.js` how should i go about exempting the custom headers from being sent to the third party API

The Axios instance created is

```
  var instance = axios.create();
    var config = {
      method: "get",
      url: "//thirdPartyApi",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const response = instance(config);
```

and in the `main.js` file i have

```
Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common["customHeader"] = Tokenized;
```

where Tokenized is my custom Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Solution 1 - use different Axios instance for both API's (clean and easy)
2. Solution 2 - write custom [request interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) and remove the header based on URL of the request...

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, Solution 1 was the way to go atleast for me. Interceptors seemed excessive especially for the one request. for anyone that finds this i had to add `var instance = axios.create({transformRequest: (headers) => { delete headers.common;}, });` : Remove all shared headers and that worked.

Comment: btw why are you using `transformRequest` ? You are creating new instance with no common headers. Also transformRequest is (from the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)) "only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH' and 'DELETE'"

Comment: I have read the **docs**, thanks for that, but for some weird reason transforming the request and putting the one header that is receivable by the third Party which is **application/json** was the only way i saw possible and it worked. This might bring about issues in the future, but i guess making two separate axios instances for the request would be a better way to go about it.

Comment: I agree that making two separate Axios instances is better solution, I just don't understand why `transformRequest` is needed. I do not think there are any headers Axios adds by default but I can be mistaken....